# close dialog box programmatically c#

Tags: c#, vb.net

In my application I want to close the opened dialog box by coding. I searched on web I got one solution but it is closing whole application, where I want to only the dialog box should get close.

```
AppActivate("Browse For Folder")
SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}")
```

Also the `Application.OpenForms` not giving me control to the opened dialog box.

Comment: is this some dialog not developed by you or you don't have code.

Comment: Do you use winforms or wpf?

Comment: I am using winforms

Comment: I have developed the dialog box @Kundan Bhati

Comment: AppActivate will activate other app. is your dialog is part of some other application.

Comment: did yo inherit from any WinForms Class when you "developed the dialog box" ?

Comment: Thank you @TcKs it solved my problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `extension method` to close dialog box programmatically.

```
public static class ExtensionClassForClosing
{
    public static async Task CloseAfterXDelay(this Form form, int milliSecDelay )
    {
        await Task.Delay( milliSecDelay );
        form.Close();
    }
}
```

And then call this method before you show the form, like,

```
Label lbl = new Label();
Form frm = new Form();
lbl.Left = 200;
lbl.Top = 50;
frm.Controls.Add(lbl);    
frm.CloseAfterXDelay( 1000 ); //After 1 Sec    
frm.ShowDialog();
```

This is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is not dialog box (openfiledialog / savefiledialog / printdialog / ....).

Comment: NO I want to close the dialog box (openfiledialog / savefiledialog / browseforfolder).The **form.close**  will close the whole form,I just want to close the dialog box